# Sprite not showing up in flutter application using flame

Tags: flutter, dart, sprite, flame

I am following the flame tutorial for flutter [here](https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.0.0-releasecandidate.16/game.html) and was able to get my code to compile and run on a simulator (both iOS and chrome) however nothing appears when the app runs. I assume that an image of my crate.png should show up but all I see is a black screen.

Here is my main.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCrate extends SpriteComponent {
  // creates a component that renders the crate.png sprite, with size 16 x 16
  MyCrate() : super(size: Vector2.all(16));

  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('crate.png');
    anchor = Anchor.center;
  }

  @override
  void onGameResize(Vector2 gameSize) {
    // We don't need to set the position in the constructor, we can it directly here since it will
    // be called once before the first time it is rendered.
    position = gameSize / 2;
  }
}

class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  MyGame() {
    add(MyCrate());
  }
}

main() {
  final myGame = MyGame();
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: myGame,
    ),
  );
}
```

and here is my pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
name: boxgame
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flame: ^1.0.0-releasecandidate.16
  dashbook: ^0.1.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/crate.png
```

I created my assets folder in the project root directory and placed it in a folder called images.

**Edit**

I just realized there is some error output:

```
Error: Assertion failed:
../…/components/component.dart:323
parentGame.hasLayout
"\"prepare/add\" called before the game is ready. Did you try to access it on the Game constructor? Use the \"onLoad\" ot \"onParentMethod\" method instead."
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:5083:11)
    at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:5008:15)
at main.MyCrate.new.prepare (http://localhost:53993/packages/flame/src/game/mixins/fps_counter.dart.lib.js:2509:41)
at component_set.ComponentSet.new.addChild (http://localhost:53993/packages/flame/src/game/mixins/fps_counter.dart.lib.js:7041:19)
    at addChild.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:40127:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:40158:7)
at component_set.ComponentSet.new.addChild (http://localhost:53993/packages/flame/src/game/mixins/fps_counter.dart.lib.js:7040:20)
at main.MyGame.new.add (http://localhost:53993/packages/flame/src/game/mixins/fps_counter.dart.lib.js:2453:28)
at new main.MyGame.new (http://localhost:53993/packages/boxgame/main.dart.lib.js:74:10)
at main$ (http://localhost:53993/packages/boxgame/main.dart.lib.js:84:18)
at main (http://localhost:53993/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:36:29)
    at main.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:40108:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:39979:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:34926:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:35493:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:35531:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:35379:23)
    at http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:34563:46
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:39979:59)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:34926:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:35493:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:35531:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:35379:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:35400:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:40246:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:40252:13)
    at http://localhost:53993/dart_sdk.js:35751:9
```

I tried running on load before calling add but I got the same error:

```
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  MyGame() {
    MyCrate crate = MyCrate();
    crate.onLoad();
    add(crate);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that you found works fine, if you want to fix the original code you have to follow the slightly cryptic message in the stack trace:

> "prepare/add" called before the game is ready. Did you try to access
> it on the Game constructor? Use the "onLoad" or "onMount" method
> instead.

Which means that you have to move the `add`ing of the components to `onLoad` instead of having them in the game constructor like you do now. So it would look like this:

```
class MyCrate extends SpriteComponent {
  // creates a component that renders the crate.png sprite, with size 16 x 16
  MyCrate() : super(size: Vector2.all(16));

  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('crate.png');
    anchor = Anchor.center;
  }

  @override
  void onGameResize(Vector2 gameSize) {
    // We don't need to set the position in the constructor, we can it directly here since it will
    // be called once before the first time it is rendered.
    position = gameSize / 2;
  }
}

class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    await super.onLoad();
    add(MyCrate());
  }
}

main() {
  final myGame = MyGame();
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: myGame,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this worked but the following made the image show up:

```
class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  late final SpriteComponent player;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final sprite = await Sprite.load('crate.png');
    final size = Vector2.all(16.0);
    final player = SpriteComponent(size: size, sprite: sprite);

    // screen coordinates
    player.position = Vector2(0.0, 0.0);
    player.angle = 0; // 0 by default, can also be set in the constructor
    add(player); // Adds the component
  }
}

main() {
  final myGame = MyGame();
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: myGame,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

99% correct @spydo.
`Sprite.load` assumes thet the images are in `assets/images` with an "S" at the end of image

Answer (score -1):

You should fix address of assets. Check below sample :

```
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
        sprite = await Sprite.load('assets/images/crate.png');
        anchor = Anchor.center;
      }
```

Comment: thank you, however this did not solve the issue.

Comment: `Sprite.load` already assumes that your images are in `assets/image/`, so you shouldn't add it yourself.